# Docker container binds to port, but I am unable to ping it

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ping, docker

I have a running Docker container (from [this](https://index.docker.io/u/alexeiled/docker-oracle-xe-11g/) image). The container seems to be running correctly as far as I can see (the log-files are looking good and can connect via SSH to container and use SQLPlus inside it). However, I am unable to connect to the container from my host.

I started the container like this:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 49160:22 -p 49161:1521 -p 49162:8080 alexeiled/docker-oracle-xe-11g
```

I inspected the port-binding by this:

```
$ sudo docker port <container> 8080
0.0.0.0:49162
```

And when I do a `sudo docker inspect <container>` I get among others this:

```
"NetworkSettings": {
    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
    "Gateway": "172.17.42.1",
    "Bridge": "docker0",
    "PortMapping": null,
    "Ports": {
        "1521/tcp": [
            {
                "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                "HostPort": "49161"
            }
        ],
        "22/tcp": [
            {
                "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                "HostPort": "49160"
            }
        ],
        "8080/tcp": [
            {
                "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                "HostPort": "49162"
            }
        ]
    }
},
```

When I try to ping the container, the container responds:

```
$ ping 172.17.0.2
PING 172.17.0.2 (172.17.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.17.0.2: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.138 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.2: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.132 ms
```

**But I cannot connect from my host (Windows) to the Docker container**. I am running Docker inside a Ubuntu 12.04 virtual machine (in VirtualBox on Windows). I am not sure if it is a problem with Docker, with my Linux VM or with VirtualBox. I forwarded a bunch ports in VirtualBox:

[image]

This is the result of `sudo netstat -tpla`:

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 *:sunrpc                *:*                     LISTEN      542/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN      1661/sshd
tcp        0      0 *:51201                 *:*                     LISTEN      831/rpc.statd
tcp        0     80 docker:ssh              10.0.2.2:62220          ESTABLISHED 1902/sshd: vagrant
tcp6       0      0 [::]:49160              [::]:*                  LISTEN      2388/docker
tcp6       0      0 [::]:49161              [::]:*                  LISTEN      2388/docker
tcp6       0      0 [::]:56105              [::]:*                  LISTEN      831/rpc.statd
tcp6       0      0 [::]:49162              [::]:*                  LISTEN      2388/docker
tcp6       0      0 [::]:sunrpc             [::]:*                  LISTEN      542/rpcbind
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN      1661/sshd
```

**Any idea why I cannot connect from Windows to my (running) Docker container?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

You configuration seems ok to me, but I think that ports `49160-49162` should be bind to IPv4 interface not IPv6. I googled this and it seems that you encountered an open bug in docker:

- https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/2174
- https://serverfault.com/questions/545379/docker-will-only-bind-forwarded-ports-to-ipv6-interfaces

I see two solutions to your problem:

1. completely disable IPv6 on Ubuntu VM
2. or bind **directly** to the IPv4 address: -p `172.17.42.1:49162:8080`

---

Answer before edit:

You can't ping ports. Ping is using ICMP protocol.

In case you cannot connect to published port, you can check if specific service in the docker container does bind to proper network interface (f.e. `0.0.0.0`) and not to `localhost`. You can check all listening ports in container: `netstat -tpla`.

Comment: Ahh OK, I see :D When I do a `ping 172.17.0.2` to the IP address of the container, I get the expected response. But I'm still unable to connect to it... I edit my question.

Comment: Mmmm, no, unfortunately this didn't solve the problem. I think it must be something different related to my network configuration... I just download a new Ubuntu image (also Ubuntu 12.04) and installed Docker and the Oracle-XE image - and it works. It also binds to IPv6 (the output of `sudo netstat -tpla` looks exaclty the same), but it works somehow. I can access the container from my Linux VM as well as from my Windows host. But I still don't know the real source of my problems... However, thanks for your help! It's working now :)

Comment: You might need to link the docker instances.

Answer (score 2):

When you run docker in windows the construct is like this

```
Windows machine [
  Docker Virtual Box VM [ 
    Container1,
    Container2,
    ...
  ]
]
```

So when you expose a port in your container and bind it to all address in the host machine say using the `-p` parameter, the port is actually exposed in the docker virtual box VM and not on the windows machine.

Say for instance you run

```
docker run --name MyContainerWithPortExpose -d -p 127.0.0.1:43306:3306  SomeImage:V1
```

Run a `netstat` command from your windows command prompt. Strangely you will not see the `localhost:43306` port in `LISTEN` mode

Now do a `boot2docker ssh` from your `boot2docker` console to log into the docker virtual box VM
Run a `netstat` command. Vola..... you will find `localhost:43306` listed on the docker virtual box VM

Work around:

Once in the Virtual Box VM, run a `ipconfig` command and find out the IP address of the VM. Use this IP in the run docker command, instead of `127.0.0.1`
The down side to this work around is, your DHCP server can sometime play havoc by assigning different IPs each time you start the `boot2docker` virtual box VM.